# Undefined reference `ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const*)`

Tags: c++, meson-build, id3lib

I am trying to use `id3lib` in my project to get audio meta data, for now I just have this one line inside my project that use `id3lib`

I did `#include <id3/tag.h>` and then somewhere in project I have

```
    ID3_Tag myTag("/home/apoorv/Music/hello.ogg");
```

and when trying to compile it I get error

```
❯ ./build.sh
The Meson build system
Version: 0.56.0
Source dir: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer
Build dir: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build
Build type: native build
Project name: MusicPlayer
Project version: undefined
Using 'CXX' from environment with value: 'g++'
C++ compiler for the host machine: g++ (gcc 10.2.0 "g++ (GCC) 10.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: g++ ld.bfd 2.35.1
Using 'CXX' from environment with value: 'g++'
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
wx-config found: YES (/usr/bin/wx-config-gtk3) 3.0.5
Run-time dependency WxWidgets found: YES 3.0.5
Build targets in project: 1

Found ninja-1.10.1 at /usr/bin/ninja
Found runner: ['/usr/bin/ninja']
ninja: Entering directory `.'
[3/3] Linking target musicApp
FAILED: musicApp
g++  -o musicApp musicApp.p/src_app.cpp.o musicApp.p/src_frame.cpp.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -pthread -Wl,--start-group -lwx_gtk3u_media-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_aui-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_webview-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0 -Wl,--end-group
/usr/bin/ld: musicApp.p/src_frame.cpp.o: in function `Frame::Library(wxCommandEvent&)':
/home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build/../src/frame.cpp:495: undefined reference to `ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build/../src/frame.cpp:495: undefined reference to `ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build/../src/frame.cpp:495: undefined reference to `ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
./build.sh: line 12: ./musicApp: No such file or directory
```

I am using `meson` as build system, I tried adding `id3lib` as a dependency in `meson.build` but no luck

```
project('MusicPlayer', 'cpp')

src = [

  'src/app.cpp',
  'src/frame.cpp',

  ]

wx = dependency('wxwidgets', modules : ['media', 'std', 'aui'])

id3 = dependency('id3lib')

executable('musicApp', src,
  dependencies : [wx, id3])
```

I still get error

```
❯ ./build.sh
The Meson build system
Version: 0.56.0
Source dir: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer
Build dir: /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build
Build type: native build
Project name: MusicPlayer
Project version: undefined
Using 'CXX' from environment with value: 'g++'
C++ compiler for the host machine: g++ (gcc 10.2.0 "g++ (GCC) 10.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: g++ ld.bfd 2.35.1
Using 'CXX' from environment with value: 'g++'
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
wx-config found: YES (/usr/bin/wx-config-gtk3) 3.0.5
Run-time dependency WxWidgets found: YES 3.0.5
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.7.3)
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.18.4)
Run-time dependency id3lib found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:12:0: ERROR: Dependency "id3lib" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

A full log can be found at /home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

ERROR: Current directory is not a meson build directory: `/home/apoorv/repos/cpp-projects/wxWidgets/MusicPlayer/build`.
Please specify a valid build dir or change the working directory to it.
It is also possible that the build directory was generated with an old
meson version. Please regenerate it in this case.
./build.sh: line 12: ./musicApp: No such file or directory
```

I am on Arch Linux, I did install `id3lib` through `pacman`.

Answer (score 2):

id3lib doesn't ship package config (.pc) file (and it looks as have [no initention](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/5109)), you can create it yourself as described in the link and put it in PKG_CONIFG_PATH but it's simpler to find it as library:

```
cxx = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
id3 = cxx.find_library('libid3')
```

- in this case though you can't rely on/check library version at build time, only in code.